# window.requestFileSystem doesn't work in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, html5-filesystem

I try to store locally and display an image I retrieve using an Ajax call, in Cordova. Here my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

        <title>Test requestFileSystem</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
<script>
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

    function onError(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/2/26/10_francs_Mathieu_1987_F365-28_revers.jpg', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    window.onload = function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", start, false);
    }

    function start() {
        alert("dans start : deviceready fired");
        xhr.send();
    }

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        alert("xhr.onload");
        doProcess();
    }

    function doProcess() {
        alert('dans doProcess');
        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) { // here
            alert('dans requestFileSystem 1 success');
            fs.root.getFile('image.jpg', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
                alert('dans getFile 1 success');
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                    alert('dans createWriter');
                    writer.onwrite = function(e) {};
                    writer.onerror = function(e) {};

                    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'image/jpeg'});

                    writer.write(blob);

                }, function(e) {
                    console.log('Error', e);
                });
            }, function(e) {
                console.log('Error', e);
            });
        }, function(e) {
            alert('error');
            console.log('Error', e);
        });

        window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, function(fs) {
            alert('dans reqestFileSystem 2 success');
            fs.root.getFile('image.jpg', {create: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                    alert('dans file');
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = event.target.result;

                        document.body.parentNode.insertBefore(img, document.body.nextSibling);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log('Error', e);
                });
            }, function(e) {
                console.log('Error', e);
            });
        }, function(e) {
            console.log('Error', e);
        });

    };

    //xhr.send();</script>
```

Problem is, it seems the success function of the first window.requestFileSystem call (commented "here") is never called. Neither is the error function called. My "dans doProcess" alert is displayed, and then nothing happens anymore. I'm testing with XCode and the iOS simulator. Any idea?

Comment: hi   use 0 instd of 1024 * 1024 and check iam not sure just try @Traroth

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Put a try&catch around the code in doProcess, you may get useful info. Also check if you allowed your app to access the file system.

Comment: Did you solve this issue????